# How to debug windows EFI modules during boot using IDA Pro's windbg?

Tags: ida, kernel-mode, uefi

I wanted to debug winload.efi using IDA Pro 7.7, but for some weird reason there is no windbg in the list of debuggers in case of EFI files, even tho I can easily debug the kernel using IDA Pro's windbg.

I can already debug winload.efi using windbg and there is no problem with that, so how can I force IDA pro to list windbg in the list of debuggers in case of EFI files?

I can run IDA pro and attach during boot, thus technically debug the winload.efi, but when I open the IDB file of the winload.efi, there is no windbg option in the debuggers.

Note that I have used `bcdedit /bootdebug {current}`, therefore debugger will break In winload.efi during boot.

Comment: This sort of questions is probably best asked by sending an email to the Hex-Rays support. Within your software maintenance period you can usually expect rather swift responses. With some luck Igor will pop by and see and answer it here, though.

Comment: @0xC0000022L Correct, but using stackexchange is better because the answer would help other people who would face the  same problem in the future.

Comment: Uhm, actually taking the direct route doesn't preclude answering your own Q&A, once you learned something new from contacting their support, does it?

Comment: If you are allowed to run this efi in an emulator like QEMU, do gdb debug instead. I tried it and it works well. Just remember to rebase the program.